# Data is not getting displayed in the html data, when it is stored in db.json

Tags: json, angular, angular-material

I have stored some data in db.json. In the ts file I have used the get function and received it in a variable. The data is coming through successfully( I checked using console.log). However it is not displaying in the html table i have created.

Below is my html file

```
<p>people works!</p>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

<!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
      The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"> {{i+1}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="company">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Comapnay </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.company}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Symbol Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="email">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="address">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Address </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Active </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.active}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let j = index"><button (click) = "detail(j)"> {{element.action}} </button></td>
  </ng-container>

 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
 </table>
  
<div id = "Detail">
  {{userDetail.id}}<br>
  {{userDetail.name}}<br>
  {{userDetail.company}}<br>
  {{userDetail.email}}<br>
  {{userDetail.active}}<br>
  {{userDetail.action}}
 </div>
```

And the next code is my ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { user } from './userInterface';

@Component({
selector: 'app-people',
templateUrl: './people.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./people.component.css']
})
export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit {

 displayedColumns=["id","name","company","email","address","active","action"];
 UserDb:user[]=[];

 dataSource = this.UserDb;
 userDetail: user={
  id: 0,
  name: '',
  company: '',
   email: '',
  address: '',
  active: false,
  action: ''
};

detail(rowid: number) {
  this.userDetail = this.UserDb[rowid];
}


 constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 

 }

 ngOnInit(): void {

  console.log("im working");
  this._http.get("http://localhost:3002/posts").subscribe((users:any)=>{
    this.UserDb = users;
    console.log(this.UserDb);
   })

 }

 }
```

`

My entire data is being shown in the console.

[data in the console. But not showing under the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u85xE.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks that `dataSource` gets the value of `UserDB` **before** `UserDB` is populated. So, you get valid data in the console; but not in HTML. Why do you use two variables in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the error in the code. Actually, the variables used in json needs to be exactly the same to the one used in the front-end part of the program.Like in my ts code i have used 'id' and 'name'.But in json the same variables I've written as 'Id' and 'Name'. Hence, the problem.